# Pointer and use of it: *&p and &*p? are they legal?

Tags: c

Hi I am new to C programming. I try to figure out what do *&p and &*p pointer mean ? Does it ever come to help?

```
q=*&p
```

Comment: Has it ever helped you?  I've never used it.

Answer (score 3):

They are no-ops, except that they can produce compile-time errors. Therefore, they could be useful in a macro as an assertion. `*&l` ensures that `l` is an lvalue, and `&*p` ensures that `p` is (implicitly convertible to) a pointer.

```
#define ASSERT_LVALUE(l)  (void)(*&(l))
#define ASSERT_POINTER(p) (void)(&*(p))

int main(void) {
    int* p;
    int i;

    ASSERT_LVALUE(i);
    ASSERT_LVALUE(3);   /* error: lvalue required as unary ‘&’ operand */

    ASSERT_POINTER(p);
    ASSERT_POINTER(i);  /* error: invalid type argument of unary ‘*’ (have ‘int’) */
    ASSERT_POINTER(3);  /* error: invalid type argument of unary ‘*’ (have ‘int’) */

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `&*p` works on arrays. So it actually tests whether `p` is implicitly convertible to pointer